# "roscpp" not working in ros2 humble

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, mavlink

I migrated to **ros2 humble**. I had a project in **ros1 noetic** and wanted to run that on the new machine. For my project to work, I need **mavros** package. While installing it, I got errors as it depends on **roscpp**. I checked on roscpp website and found that roscpp is not supported for ros2 yet. Now I am stuck on how to handle it. Any **alternative** or **solution**, please?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

The [roscpp](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp) is the C++ implementation of ROS 1, as you pointed out.

Fortunately, [mavros](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros) provides ROS 2 support, and it is available on [their GitHub](https://github.com/mavlink/mavros). The package information can be found in the [ROS Index](https://index.ros.org/p/mavros/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. You are right, upon investigating further, I found that roscpp and rospy of ROS1 are replaced by rclcpp and rclpy in ROS2. And These are not actually a sort of plugins but the foundation upon which ROS is built.

Comment: I am glad that it worked. To mark this as solved, please click the gray "check-mark" icon located on the left side of this answer. Once selected, the icon will turn green to confirm your choice.